# Laravel perform Update/edit inside index view is it possible?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

is it possible to use the **index view** to perform **update/edit** at the same time using **modal form**? i have **index view** with table displaying the data,and inside the table it has button named [**edit and delete**] now i want to perform edit/update once the edit button is click then modal form will come out..? but whenever is use the modal form it will show error like this image.[image]

**This is my Controller:**

```
public function show_setup()
{
    $batch=Batch::all();

    return view('setup.show_batch',compact('batch'));
}

public function edit_batch(request $request)
{
        $batch = Batch::find ($request->id);
        $batch->batch_name = $request->batch_name;
        $batch->save();

        return redirect()->back();

}
```

**My view**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Batch</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach($batch as $bt)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$bt->batch_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_batch" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit </a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>

</form>   <!-- Modal-->
<div id="edit_batch" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Edit Batch</h5>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                        
                <form action="setup/batch/edit" method="POST">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    {{ method_field('PUT') }}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>School Year</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="School Year" name="batch_name" value="{{$batch->batch_name}}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       <!--End batch Modal-->
```

Comment: Is it when showing the modal or after submitting the form ?

Comment: no it is when i go to the url its automatically that error come out but when i remove the {{batch_name}}inside the modal value it shows the page but modal value is empty..

Comment: can you add your js code ?

Comment: i'm not using js code for this what u see that is my code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to get the `batch_name` from the collection `$batch` you have to pass the data you want using the javaScript the data you need are the `id` and the `batch_name`

Here is an example :

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Batch</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach($batch as $bt)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$bt->batch_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" id="editBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_batch" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-id="{{ $bt->id }}" data-batch_name="{{ $bt->batch_name }}">Edit </a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>

</form>

<!-- Modal-->
<div id="edit_batch" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Edit Batch</h5>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                        
                <form action="setup/batch/edit" method="POST">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                    <input id="batch_id" type="hidden" name="id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>School Year</label>
                        <input id="batch_name" type="text" placeholder="School Year" name="batch_name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End batch Modal-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.editBtn').on('click',function(e) 
    {
        var link    = $(this);
        batch_id = link.data("id");
        batch_name = link.data("batch_name");
        $("#batch_id").val(batch_id);
        $("#batch_name").val(batch_name);
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: Check my updated answer and for the js part you can add what ever you did to show the modal :)